# git add didnt add the entire code base and code now being overwritten

Tags: git

Not sure what exactly happened. I pushed my code this Saturday at around 5pm with changes in some html and .css file. I was at the head of the folder and the git log shows that I've committed something.

```
commit 6f05c4013fc78118f1c1c2c52eafcf5f6af6d2ef
Author: llu13701 <49617749+llu13701@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Sat Jan 30 17:32:00 2021 -0500

    complete css react

 Reddit_app/__pycache__/forms.cpython-37.pyc                              | Bin 2560 -> 2590 bytes
 Reddit_app/__pycache__/models.cpython-37.pyc                             | Bin 5655 -> 5724 bytes
 Reddit_app/__pycache__/urls.cpython-37.pyc                               | Bin 823 -> 823 bytes
 Reddit_app/__pycache__/views.cpython-37.pyc                              | Bin 4154 -> 4285 bytes
 Reddit_app/migrations/__pycache__/0008_post_photo.cpython-37.pyc         | Bin 0 -> 590 bytes
 Reddit_app/migrations/__pycache__/0009_auto_20210130_1653.cpython-37.pyc | Bin 0 -> 573 bytes
 Reddit_app/migrations/__pycache__/0010_post_upload_photo.cpython-37.pyc  | Bin 0 -> 600 bytes
 media/images/2977694_copy.jpg                                            | Bin 0 -> 80890 bytes
 media/images/5616.jpg                                                    | Bin 0 -> 15480 bytes
 9 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

The strange thing that I didnt notice than was that the file that I actually changed, including base.html, and .css file. wasn't committed.

I didn't notice this until this Morning. My teammates told me that she has pushed the code and I did a simple git pull to pull the latest code. There was no conflict and no error message.

Now all my code on .html and .css are simply gone. I am wondering if there is a way to get my file back, I've tried git revert head-1 to the Saturday version, problem is that the Saturday version wasn't correct. Is there a way that I can recover the file? Also can someone tell you what possibly cause such an issue?

Comment: Sorry, Git cannot help you get back what was not committed. And we can't tell you what went wrong except that what you thought you were adding and committing was not what you added and committed. You instead added some Python compile cache files, which probably should not be committed; add pycache to your .gitignore to avoid this. In the future, don't use `git commit -a` use `git add`, use `git status`and `git diff --staged` to check what's about to be committed, and `git commit -v` to show what's about to be committed while you're writing the commit message.

Comment: However, if the files ever existed at all, you should still have them sitting in your checkout. Git would not have blown away your edits nor deleted your files unless you told it to like with `git restore`. If you're using Git on the command line, check what commands you ran with `history`.

Comment: @Schwern is "ran with history" the same as git log?

Comment: No, there's a command called [`history`](https://www.howtogeek.com/465243/how-to-use-the-history-command-on-linux/) which will list the last few hundred commands you ran in your shell. `history | grep git` will show you all the Git commands you ran, assume you're not using a command alias or GUI.

Comment: @Schwern oh yeah. just did it.. it shows that i did git add . git commit -m "xyz", git push.. sign

Comment: Try `git ls-tree --name-only -r HEAD` to see whether your missing files are anywhere in the most recent commit. If not, you might try an earlier commit or a different branch instead of HEAD. But if you _never_ committed them _ever_ on _any_ branch then if you don't see them they are well and truly gone.

Comment: @llu13701 `git add .` would have added them, unless they're ignored. Even if they were ignored, the files should still exist. Are you sure these files existed? For example, could you have written them and forgotten to save them? Could they be in a different directory? In the future, avoid `git commit -m`. It encourages poor commit messages, and you don't get that last chance to check that you're committing what you think you are.

Comment: You don't need to commit your files for git to add them to the object database.  https://github.com/ethomson/git-recover may help, but if you actually _did_ commit the files, then they exist somewhere in a branch.